# Django manage.py runserver command does not work

Tags: python, django

So I downloaded python (latest version) with everything checked and added it to PATH.I installed django, created everything I need, got the django files, but when i run python manage.py runserver it ptinys a lot of stuff, but in the end it prints

I don't know anything about django or pip or python shell, I was following a tutorial but this doesnt work for me.

```
    C:\djangoproject>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoproject'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoproject'

C:\djangoproject>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoproject'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoproject'
```

It should just run with no error and run the server.

Comment: did you rename your project?

Comment: Actually it created a folder named djangoproject, and inside it was manage.py and another folder called djangoproject.I just made it so there is a single djangoproject with all the files in it + manage.py.

Comment: Did you move the contents from the second "djangoproject" folder to the same level as "manage.py"? If you did then you broke the file structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your Django file structure should look like this:

```
djangoproject/
    manage.py
    djangoproject/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

**__init__.py** tells Python to treat the parent directory as a module.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoproject'
```

By rearranging the folder structure, you've stopped Python from treating that folder as a module. Manage.py needs that module to perform its operations.